# C++ adding more chars?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

Is it possible to replace single char with multiple chars? for example : `i` is replaced with `je`

So far I can only replace letter `u` with `o`:

```
    char text[100];
    cout << "Input text : ";
    cin.getline(text, sizeof(text));
    replace(text, text+strlen(text), 'u', 'o');
    cout << "Output text : " << text << endl;
```

Comment: can you give one example testcase and expected output?

Comment: with char array it is tedious. Use std::string that has erase and insert.

Comment: Yes! You would need to find the location of i in the array. i.e. make a for loop and search for the element. You would then want to create a new array of size [size+1]. Then go up until you are at the index of the previous found element, copying the chars while looping. Then insert your 2 characters, then continue looping copying the remaining elements over. If you want to keep it under the same name make text an element on the heap with new, just make sure to delete it when done to avoid any leaks :).

Comment: @ÖöTiib or better, `std::string::replace()`

Comment: @DanielTodd or, if the array has enough room to accommodate the larger size, just shift and insert chars in-place, no need to allocate new memory.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Im not going to lie Ive been doing so much C I forgot about std, and yeah I overlooked the whole 100 size

Comment: @VyushAgarwal example, if I type ``insert`` then the output should say ``jensert``
just for reminder, ``i`` is replaced with ``je``